# Bind request method POST

Tags: go, struct, go-echo

I have a problem with binding my request, because there are a lot of parameters, so I used struct containing param.

```golang
package api
import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "net/http"
    "trains-api/domain/models"
    "trains-api/domain/services"
)

type reqCreate struct {
    RequestNotifi  models.ResquestCreateNotifi  
}
func CreateNotification (c echo.Context) error {
    req := reqCreate{}

    if err := c.Bind(req); err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, err)
    }
}
```

```golang
package models

type RequestCreateNotifi struct {
    Name_param1     string    `db:"Name_param1"`
    Name_param2     string    `db:"Name_param2"`
    ....
    Name_param_n    string    `db:"Name_paramN"`
}
```

error at `if err := c.Bind(req); err != nil`

```golang
r = {interface {} | string } "reflect: Elem of invalid type"
```

Comment: What is c.Bind?

Comment: func CreateNotification (c echo.Context) error {
}
@CeriseLimón

Comment: other package , import model package

Comment: Please edit the question to show the import path of the package you are using.  Please show where the error was reported.

Comment: yes . i sorry i begin with stackoverflow . @CeriseLimón . i done

Comment: @ThinhPham - try passing a pointer as it's the only thing I can see wrong with what you've given. The error message just doesn't make sense to me. `if err := c.Bind(&req) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the JSON equivalent of each field in the model like so:

```
package models
type RequestCreateNotifi struct {
    Name_param1     string    `json:"name_param1" db:"Name_param1"`
    Name_param2     string    `json:"name_param2" db:"Name_param2"`
    ....
    Name_param_n    string    `json:"name_param_n" db:"Name_param n"`
}
```

This json field specifies how the field is represented in the request so it can bind it to the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the pointer

```
req := reqCreate{}

if err := c.Bind(&req); err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't bind automatically query parameter using Post methode for security reasons according to [issue#1670](https://github.com/labstack/echo/issues/1670), the way to do it is using echo.QueryParamsBinder

```
type Query struct {
Param1 string `query:"param1"`
Param2 string `query:"param2"`
}

...
query := new(Query)
err := echo.QueryParamsBinder(ctx).String("param1", &query.Param1).String("param2", &query.Param2).BindError()
...
```